# How can I automate populating an array using a named range on a specific worksheet?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, named

The named range is `SheetNames`, on a worksheet named `Consolidation`, cell B3 to B101 and the array is `Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select`:

```
Sub Insert_Formula()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        ws.Range("F3:F50").Formula = "=SUMIFS(Jul!$K:$K,Jul!$H:$H,$C$1,Jul!$J:$J,$C3)"
    Next ws
  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Just to be clear, what exactly isn't working?

Comment: GraphicsMuncher, the code is working but everytime I change the worksheet names, I have to manually copy-paste them into the array (e.g. "Sheet1", "Sheet2", etc.). I can automate this using a named range, but I don't know how to integrate it into the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this answers your question. If you are looking to iterate through every sheet in your workbook, instead of explicitly calling out their names you can just use

```
Sub Insert_Formula() 

Application.ScreenUpdating = false

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Range("F3:F50").Formula = "=SUMIFS(Jul!$K:$K,Jul!$H:$H,$C$1,Jul!$J:$J,$C3)"
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

End Sub
```

Alternatively if you want to use the specific sheet name you specified with the worksheet names you can try this

```
Sub Insert_Formula()

    For Each cell In Range("sheetNames")
        Sheets(cell.Text).Range("F3:F50").Formula = "=SUMIFS(Jul!$K:$K,Jul!$H:$H,$C$1,Jul!$J:$J,$C3)"
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Silenxor, thanks for your response. I want to use a named range (called "SheetNames"), containing multiple worksheet names, to populate the array. Your second code seems to be the most plausible solution, but I am getting Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range.

Comment: you might have to put some workbook level code if this working across multiple workbooks. For example ActiveWorkbook.Range("SheetNames") and ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Text).Range... etc.

Comment: Also try stepping through your code to see where you are getting that error, ie is it even getting into the for loop or is the it erroring on the line For Each cell In Range("sheetNames") cos that could mean it cant find the name range sheetNames. If it's erroring inside the for loop, it could mean that it couldn't find a specific sheet name in your named range?

Comment: Silenxor, this is only for a single workbook, as all relevant inputs are in a single file. From debugging, I get the error on this line: Sheets(cell.Text).Range("F3:F50").Formula = "=SUMIFS(Jul!$K:$K,Jul!$H:$H,$C$1,Jul!$J:$J,$C3)"

Comment: Silenxor, my named list has blank cells and apparently the macro does not like that. Once I removed the blank cells, the macro works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Haha yeah definitely blank cells won't work! The code I wrote is just to give you an idea of what you can do, it isn't error handled or tested, that will be up to you to tweak and modify for you particular needs!